# Broken bounce rate stats since April 13th

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-tracking

We are using Google Analytics for our site that has huge traffic. We are in trouble with some interesting -and surely not good- changes in stats since last 50 days(started on April 13). Bounce rates has doubled, our "time on site" value decreased about 5 minutes and unique visitor counts unexpectedly increased very high. In addition, our pageview stats has no change. We are investigating cause of this issue for several days. We know, these symptomps shows us there is a problem about user sessions. We are loosing user's analytics sessions on somewhere on our site. We got a tip:

We noticed that, our search page has 2.5x more value for "landing page" since 50 days. We are using _trackEvent method for tracking some user interactions on our search page. When we followed the utmb cookie of google analytics(that, as we know, it stores user session for analytics), we noticed that, when we track an event, utmb cookie value changes.

So, the question is, is it normal to tracking events changes to utmb cookie? May this problem be the reason we live in?

#### UPDATE

We are using ga.js as self-hosted on our servers. Our tracking code is so simple:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-235XXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.ourdomain.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowHash', false]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

#### UPDATE 2

We removed setAllowHash parameter and started to host ga.js on google as default usage. Problem still continues.

Comment: Hi, did you change anything else on April 13th ? Like adding a sharing widget or any other element that could use GA on its own ? You're typically in the situation where GA cookies get resets between page views, look at the first number in each cookies and check when they change from page to page. Do you mix traditionnal syntax and async ?

Comment: We checked what happened on April 14th but we couldn't found any change that can be affect to this situation. We are hosting ga.js on our servers and using async syntax. We use analytics for about a year in this way.

Comment: Are you using the old syntax or the async syntax? Can you post your current code?

Comment: We are using async syntax. I added some code to question. We are not using so complex implementations.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your updated question. self-hosting ga.js is a big problem, this is not a simple tracking code anymore if you self-host ga.js.

Comment: I'm also not sure what is your question anymore. Your question was originally if cookies utmb cookie changing was the root cause and I guess I addressed this on my answer. So I guess you're just looking for an explanation to bounce rate, but I'm not sure anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having exactly the same problem. It also started on 14th April 2012, bounce rates going up, new visits also, shortening Time on site and lowering pages per visit...
Pageviews remain the same, which means that for some reason, users are 'losing' __utma cookie, responsible for tracking the user as unique.

One thing I found interesting through GA - in my case this problem does not show for Opera 11.64. It holds its previous value of about 14% bounce rate. Other browsers (mainly new versions of Firefox and Chrome) went through the roof (bounce rate of 65-90%).

I am talking about a website with couple of hundreds of thousands of visits...
Tommorow I will try change a few things, and post back if I find anything useful.

UPDATE

I have updated the code to the new one

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>
```

instead of the old one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("XX-XXXXXXXX-X");
    pageTracker._setDomainName(".example.com");
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>
```

The difference in `_setDomainName` is that in new code it doesn't have the leading dot(.) in domain name, and there seems to be the problem with the old code.
I must add that I'm not having any trouble with the other website that doesn't have `_setDomainName` part, and still is running the old code.
I also found a blog post about the same problem:
http://diegoscataglini.com/2010/08/17/118/google-analytics-setdomain-beware/

Anyway, now things are back to normal. Bounce rate back to 11%, time on site going up as well as Pages / Visit. 
When you change the code cookies will be recreated for all users, making them new visitors coming directly to your site. In a day or two (depending on number of visits), as people use your site as they do normally, statistics go back to normal.

I had to wait couple of days before reporting back, and I hope this will solve your problem too.

Comment: Did you find anything useful?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! We have dot char on our setDomainName parameter too. But, we have a lot of subdomains and -I think- we must use dot char to track these subdomains correctly. Do you have some subdomains and can you track these subdomains correctly without dot char prefixed domain parameter?

Comment: I have just copied the tracking code from the GA admin page, where it is set that I want to track a domain with multiple subdomains and the code Google provides doesn't contain leading dot. I'm not tracking these subdomains separately, or having any filters by subdomain, but visits to these pages are in GA also.
As you can see from the code I posted, we are not hosting the ga.js file, so that is not the reason for the high bounce rate.

Comment: We'll try your solution. I hope, that will solve our problem too.

Comment: We experienced that as well.  In our case, there were two analytics accounts being used on the same site.  The two accounts were not both setting domain using  pageTracker._setDomainName(".example.com");  one was using default.  What happens is that accounts share the same cookie.  So each analytics account was toggling the cookie back and forth and resetting the visit.  Multiple accounts on the same page is not recommend but, if you have good reason, make sure to set all accounts to the exact same cookie domain.

Comment: Hi Zagor/ We are still trying your suggestion. I'll return a feedback when we sure about "what is happenning" :)

Comment: It worked! We tried a lot of things but removing leading dot from domain on setDomainName param solved our problem. Removing leading dot caused "self-referral sub domains" problem but we fixed that by adding our domain to setIgnoredRef param. Here is a good explanation about problem and solution: http://www.roirevolution.com/blog/2011/01/google_analytics_subdomain_tracking.php

Comment: I think Google has changed something on processing analytics data about setDomainName on April. We contacted some technical guys from Google about that issue but we couldn't get an explanation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking aloud, perhaps this could be attributed to a popular browser suddenly supporting "do not track" or GA suddenly respecting the setting.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the utmb cookie is an expected behavior for _trackEvent -- from the [Event Tracking API docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEventTracking#_gat.GA_EventTracker_._trackEvent):

> By default, the event hit sent by _trackEvent() will impact a
>   visitor's bounce rate.

One place to loose session data is with subdomains -- For example, if you've got a mixture of www.domain.com & domain.com links on your site. If you're not using it already, you could try adding _setDomainName before the _trackPageview call:

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.yourDomain.com']);
```

Comment: I understand impact of trackEvent usage as when we track an event with default opt_noninteraction option, and then user exits from that page, that intearaction don't save as "bounce". But our problem is, bounce rates are exteremely rising. I don't think that problem is about that. Also we are already using setDomainName method for all our subdomins as ".ourdomain.com".

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. The utmb cookie stores the hit count for a session and when you track an event or a pageview the hit count is increased by one.

This is used in GA internals to control some limits.

Once this counter reaches 500 it won't send any more hits for that session. Each session in analytics can only have 500 hits.

**UPDATE: 2012-06-12**

Based on the code you posted I have a few concerns:

- You should *NEVER* self-host ga.js. This file changes as new features are added to GA. This might explain the bounce-rate changes or might not. You might be sending data that is not what ga is expecting anymore as they might have changed the protocol a little bit.
- `_setAllowHash` is deprecated by now. If you're using now you should keep using it, but if you have any pages without that call that might be causing cookies to be reset. So if all your pages use that, keep it that way, if some pages use and some pages don't, than remove and make sure not a single page has it anymore. You need to be consistent with GA settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But change on utmb cookie is not only counter. For example, my utmb cookie value was 53926837.3.9.1338755523960. When I run a trackEvent method it changes to 53926837.4.9.1338755592983. Is this normal too?

Comment: Yes, as you can see the 3 becomes a 4, that's your hit counter. The last number might be a timestamp of the last hit. I don't know, it's not very well documented. Can I ask why do you care?

Comment: Our bounce rate growing unexpectedly for last 2 months. We're tracking our site with gemius also and everything is as expected there. So, we are trying to understand why bounce rate, visitor counts growing and time on site descreasing extremely.